# Spark on Mesos Memory Limit

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

Recently I am setting up Spark on Mesos Cluster. The biggest problem I have encountered is how to limit the resource offered to one single task.

While I can limit the total number of CPU cores used by a Spark Task with `spark.cores.max`, there is no `spark.memory.max` for memory.

While I have tasks setting a large `spark.executor.memory` e.g. `64 GB`, but rather low `spark.executor.cores`, as a result, all memory got eaten up by the task and no other tasks could be launched in the cluster.

I want to ask if there is a way to limit the memory offered to spark tasks.

Comment: Have you tired using [roles](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/roles/) and [quota](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/quota/)?

Comment: @janisz Please correct me if I am wrong. If I have 5 roles and each having a quota of 5% of total memory, does it mean that they can consume 5~80% of the total memory?

Comment: Correct: _"In Mesos, a quota is a guaranteed resource allocation that a role may rely on; in other words, a minimum share a role is entitled to receive."_